# Exterior door mounting plate - replacing door hardware

Tags: doors, front-door

I am trying to replace the hardware on my front door to install a smart lock. The issue that has arisen is that the old hardware left a large discoloration on the door. The new hardware does not cover the discoloration (it is separate pieces rather than 1 solid piece like the old one). Is there some sort of thin mounting plate with holes in the proper spots that I could use to cover the discoloration before installing the new hardware? I searched online but couldn't find anything for this purpose. The size is 2.5"x18".

[image: front door]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic here. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Hi @DanielGriscom. The tour says you should ask about "Which tools, materials, and best practices for home improvement task" and that was what I was trying to ask (what part to use for the job). And I don't see anything in the "don't ask about" section that is applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two reasons for these products - security and appearance. For security, you typically want something that also covers the gap between the edge of the door and the door frame, to prevent jimmying the lock, or something that covers front, back and side of the door to make it harder to get to the lock mechanism. But for appearance, all you need is a flat plate with holes in the right places.

Most of the products I found in a quick search with predrilled holes appear to be much shorter. If you can't find an exact match (holes in the right places and long enough to cover the desired area), get a [plain plate](https://amzn.to/35t2ldy):
[image]
and use a hole saw to drill holes where needed.